# how to set file as a variable in bash

Tags: bash, file, variables, for-loop

I am new in bash scripting but I would like to set some files as variables in for loop in bash script. I have this code:

```
a=home/my_directory/*.fasta
b=home/my_directory/*.aln

for i in {1..14}   # I have 14 files in my_directory with file extension .fasta
do
clustalo -i $a -o $b  # clustalo is a command of Clustal Omega software, -i is 
                      # input file, -o is output file
done
```

I just want to use all my fasta files in my_directory and create another 14 new aln files. But with this code it doesnt work because Clustal program doesnt recognize this set files. So if you can help I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know there are exactly 14 files, do this:

```
for i in {1..14}; do
    clustalo -i home/my_directory/$a.fasta -o home/my_directory/$b.aln
done
```

If you want to process all of the `*.fasta` files, however many there are, then do:

```
for file in home/my_directory/*.fasta; do
    clustalo -i "$file" -o "${file%.fasta}.aln"
done
```

To understand this, `${file%.fasta}` gives us `$file` with the `.fasta` extension stripped off.

If you want to store the file names in a variable first, the best thing to do is to use an array variable. You do that by adding parentheses around the variable assignment, and then accessing the array values with the strange syntax `"${array[@]}"`.

```
files=(home/my_directory/*.fasta)

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    clustalo -i "$file" -o "${file%.fasta}.aln"
done
```

Comment: and is it possible to save these new files into new directory?